New processor not showing up in Ghidra on macOS
I added a new processor to Ghidra and it's showing up on Linux but not on macOS.
Any suggestions?
I filed this issue just in case.

This feels like either 1) it’s not looking in the right place; 2) it’s failing to load, for some reason (e.g. dependencies). Hopefully Ghidra has enough trace to debug this, or you can debug Ghidra itself and step thorough at the point it’s loading things.

The module manifest file was missing.
